# How to create a GRE tunnel from IPv4 address to IPv6 address?

Tags: tunneling

Is it possible to tunnel from an IPv4 address to IPv6 address?

The IPv6 server is a large server allowed a single IPv4 address but virtually unlimited IPv6 addresses, so I want to connect IP addresses from smaller servers which allow one or more IPv4 addresses to the IPv6 server which has more resources and allows more stuff to be consolidated on it.